# myphpadmin get error after change the root password and not getting access denied

Tags: phpmyadmin

it was work really fine, then i created a new database and change the privilege of two users,

it is stop working

first I got access denied and then I change the password in config.inc.php
then access denied disappear
now I have this error

phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

Comment: Can you connect through the command line client using the new password? In `config.inc.php`, do you have any line like `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']` and if so, what is it set to?

Comment: $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']     = 'config';    // Authentication method (config, http or cookie based)?

Comment: I think the next step should be making sure the server is running and that you can connect through another means, can you connect through the command line client? If not, can you verify if the server daemon is running?

Comment: I got " ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)" when I tried to connect throw terminal

Comment: not sure what you mean about server daemon but when I run "pgrep -x mysqld" I got "34937"

Answer (score 0):

I have not resolve the issue, but I use laravel valet instead